# DataSnap Server - Get Client Info (IP and Port)

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have a Client application that communicates with a DataSnap Server using HTTP.
In the TDSServer OnConnect event I want to retrieve Information (IP and Port) about the Client that has just connected, so I do the following:

```
procedure TServerContainer.DSServer1Connect(
  DSConnectEventObject: TDSConnectEventObject);
var
  userIP, userPort: String;
begin
  userIP := DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.IpAddress;
  userPort := DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.ClientPort;
end;
```

I am able to get the Client IP using the **IpAddress** property, but I can't get the Client Port, because the **ClientPort** property is an empty String.

If I use TCP instead of HTTP to communicate with my Server, I can get both information right, but in my application I neeed to use HTTP.

Am I doing something wrong or is there an another way to retrieve this information?

Thanks,

PS: The Delphi version I am using is Seattle.